# Is there any Java library which supports both Microsoft office and Open Office?

Tags: java, apache-poi, jexcelapi

As Apache POI supports Microsoft office and JExcelApi supports Open Office, is there any Java library which supports both Microsoft office and Open Office?

Note: In the `pom.xml` file we are using either POI and JExcel utilities in order to fetch/read data from the Excel sheet in Microsoft office and Open Office respectively.

So my question: Is there any library which supports both?

Comment: http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/ states that JExcel API supports `Excel 95, 97, 2000, XP, and 2003 workbooks`. There's no word about Open Office. Anyway, OO has its own [Java API](http://www.openoffice.org/api/) ([guide](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide)). I don't know any library that would be able to open both MS and OO documents.

Comment: Why do you need one library that supports both? You could also just use two libraries, one for MS Office and one for Open Office support.

Comment: What do you need to do? Get text out? Read rich values? Write changes?

Answer (score 4):

Aspose covers all of Microsofts formats, but it is not free and not open source.

Regarding open source Java API, you can find a review on each available java library here,

http://www.esupu.com/open-source-office-document-java-api-review/

Apache UNO Java library supports all according to my knowledge and it's free and open source but it need a Open Office installation to process and it's documentation is heavy and not that much clear

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no library that would support both formats. If you don't want to use a library (and write the needed code) for each format, you can try a workaround.

Use a converter to convert `.xls` to `.odt` (or the other way around), then use your favourite library to handle that one format.

Available converters I found via quick Googling, I'm sure you'll find more:

- [JODConverter](http://code.google.com/p/jodconverter/) - no longer maintained for a year and a half, but could work
- [Programmatic Document Conversion with OpenOffice](http://www.chrispliakas.com/content/programmatic-document-conversion-openoffice) - an article that shows how to use headless OO to convert MS Office documents

Consider converting both formats to something more friendly, like a [CSV](https://blogs.oracle.com/sebsto/entry/using_openoffice_api_to_conver) (more [CSV](https://github.com/znerd/ods2csv)) or XML.

Answer (score -1):

docx4j is a Java library for creating and manipulating Microsoft Open XML (Word docx, Powerpoint pptx, and Excel xlsx) files.

[Docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j)

Comment: Exactly. How does it support both MS Office and Open Office documents?