# Read Open Source Version of Excel Files in Java

Tags: java, openoffice-calc

I know that for Java, there is Apache POI.

Is there anything for OpenOffice Calc (or other open source program like Excel) that lets me obtain the data in Java?

Comment: [Is there any Java library which supports both Microsoft office and Open Office?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17788317/5221149)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Did you do a web search for this? What did you find? What is still unclear?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jOpenDocument library](http://www.jopendocument.org/) for reading and manipulating Calc files. See [this example](http://www.jopendocument.org/start_spreadsheet_2.html) for more information.